# backbonejs this.el is undefined for template view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

https://gist.github.com/stephenvisser/2711454

I use this gist for navigation.

I have a view as follows. This view is for a dom (#blog-list-container) inside a template. template is loaded with the gist navigation.

```
app.BlogListView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: '#blog-list-container',

renderBlog: function(item) {
    var blogView = new app.BlogShortView({
        model: item
    });
    this.$el.append(blogView.render().el);
},

render: function() {
    this.collection.each(function(item) {
        this.renderBlog(item);
    }, this);
}, ....
```

I create this view and navigation as follows:

```
new Navbar({el:$('#nav-item-container')});
new Content({el:$('#container')});

new app.BlogListView();
```

So the problem is, this.el is undefined inside BlogListView. In my opinion; it doesn't pick up the dom el: #blog-list-container because it is inside the template and loaded after BlogListView is initialized. How can i overcome this?

This is my first backbonejs experiment, i hope this makes sense.

**EDIT:**

It works fine if i use jquery selector

```
  $('#blog-list-container').append(blogView.render().el);
```

But i still want to know what is the proper way to set the el property.

Comment: My advice is to not do things like `el: '#blog-list-container'`. Let the views create their own `el`s that the callers can put on the page.

Comment: good advice, but blog list view is listening for collection changes to render. There is no caller.

Comment: Using Marionette.js, you can create a CollectionView, which is a special view dedicated to data-binding to a collection and handling all the rendering / appending / destruction of the views generated from the collection.

Comment: Are you instantiating the view before #blog-list-container is available?  I've had this happen often when I'm creating the view before its element has been rendered.

Comment: this.history.on('route', listener) this listener renders the #blog-list-container. new app.BlogListView(), instantiates the view after document has loaded. so yes my problem is it. how do i handle navigation and views inside the navigated content?

Answer (score 0):

As @mu is too short advised, don't use that Backbone.js too, it isn't the best practice. Yes, you are running into the fact that it tries to append the element before it is fully rendered to the DOM.

I have never once used that first options and have never run into these kinds of problems, so I advise against it.

And I believe you left out a #:

```
$('#blog-list-container').append(blogView.render().el);
```

Comment: i used angularjs and knockoutjs before, i am using backbone for the first time. i edited the #.

Comment: Grt! By the way, if you have come from AngularJS, you are probably going to get very frustrated with Backbone.js if you are using it without a supporting framework, as Backbone.js by itself is anything but a complete framework. I thoroughly suggest using Marionette.js, which handles these types of problems for you.

Comment: I can't find a nice free marionette.js book, backbone is awesome though, for educational purposes ofcourse.

Comment: The github repo is very helpful and is how I got started - I didn't buy any books. Its pretty simple when you wrap your head around it. Study this: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md and check out the example code to start making sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

Juts add

```
return this;
```

at the end of your "render" function.
Your call `this.$el.append(blogView.render().el);` expects to have element "el" returned and you are not returning anything, (notice `.el()` part at the end of your call), so jQuery throws "undefined" error because there is nothing to return.